# Colour Effecting Heat Transfer by Radiation

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation

Is there a formula that accounts for material colour when calculating heat transfer by radiation?

Or is the statement of black absorbs and reflects more compared to white independent of heat transfer?

Comment: Colour of something is related to the wavelengths they reflect. Black absorbs most, white reflects most. Heat is typically in the IR region so the colour of something doesn't give us any information about how the body deals with ir (absorption/reflection)

Comment: I think one could model this as a blackbody modulated by wavelength-dependent emissivity. So if we had a material that was black in visible light but very reflective in IR it might (if it was of a temperature that would emit the bulk of thermal radiation as IR) radiate away heat more slowly than one would (visually) expect.